# maven dependency tree compile issue in xml-apis

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm using hibernate 4.3.0 in a maven project.When I try to run mvn dependacy:tree it shows a compliation issues for xml-apis.jar in dom4j.

[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  - xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile

If I exclude the xml-apis jar from hibarate-core like below, this issue get solved.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to solve this without excluding the jar from hibernate-core?

Comment: what is the exception that you see at compile time?

Comment: when I run the mvn dependacy:tree, it shows above "| - xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile". when I run a test case as a TESTNG test case in eclipse, error I get is, "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal". when I exclude the xml-apis jara as mentioned above error disappeared and the test case was run.