# dependency not resolved: DocumentBuilderFactory class need dependency of javax.xml.parsers in openJDK 11

Tags: ivy, openjdk-11

**Story:**
I was using JDK8 and IVY as dependency manager with ANT Builder. everything was fine. My `DocumentBuilderFactory`  class able to find `javax.xml.parsers` dependency.

**Issue:**
Now I am shifted to Open JDK11, Now `DocumentBuilderFactory` not able to find `javax.xml.parsers` dependency.

Eclipse gives me suggestions to import, but when i Import nothing happens, and already import says ***the import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder cannot be resolved***
like this:
[image: Import says dependency not resolved]

**What I Need as Solution:**
I need IVY dependency for Open JDK 11 to support  `javax.xml.parsers` for `DocumentBuilderFactory`

[image: screenshot my class need dependency :(]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing this issue too,

It was because of `DocumentBuilderFactory` is available in other packages too.

***Reason***
Sometimes `dependencies` take `transitive dependencies` along with it self

For example
Class `XYZ` is available in `jarA`, `JarB` and `JarC` too. This issue was not visible untill `Java8` but after `Java9` release, `Java9` release with ***Java Platform Module System***.

This module system restrict to have multiple classes in different jars with same name, I am not saying that we can not have same name in different classes, for this you have to write `module-info.java` and have to convert your application into `Module System`.

If you are not planning to move your application into `Module System` then you can do one this, remove the dependencies which are not required for your applications and have same named classes.

Like for your problem what you can do

- Open project in `eclipse`
- Press `ctrl` + `shit` + `T` >
- Dialog opens> write your class name which is creating problem, >
- Dialog will show the packages which contains the same `class`, Now
  find out the package which is not required or transitive property
  because of other dependency >
- `Right click` on package name and click `show in` `Package Explorer`>
- Now you will have the `jar` name, `remove` or `exclude` that jar
  from your dependency manager, Like `Gradle` or `Maven` Or `Ivy`

I know lengthy process, but its your application your love you have to maintain this.

Comment: I like that ctrl + shit ;)

Answer (score 4):

I am using Eclipse Scout v9.0, and i facing same problem when i migrated from Java 1.8 to 11. I spent hours to solve it and i finally figure it out. Using the information provided by "catalystOne Dupinder", i found out that Java 11 has its own src.jar containing the following class:

- DocumentBuilder.java
- DocumentBuilderFactory.java
- FactoryConfigurrationErro.java
- etc.
  same class as "xml-apis" thus. So what i did are the following:
- exclude the "xml-apis" from maven dependency,
- configured the build path of the module and under the "Order and Export" tab click "JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]"

What i just did is, i just exported the jar library from Java 11 to maven dependencies.

Hope this will help you guys..

Comment: Examples for the exclusion of xml-apis with maven you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881183/maven-dependency-tree-compile-issue-in-xml-apis and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456316/10318272

Answer (score 3):

---

I have resolved the same issue using the below-mentioned steps :

1. I have executed the `mvn dependency:tree` in my terminal

   **output:**

```
    [INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:3.8.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.48:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.24:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.28:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.28:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.28:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.28:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
```

2. I have exclude the xml-apis dependency from org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:3.8.1:compile

```
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
```

3.I update the maven project (Project > maven > update project)
After updating the maven project I have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

javax.xml are extracted as separate module in Java 9.

In your project's `Java build path` option, go to `Libraries` tab and change JDK from Classpath to ModulePath and this should fix this problem.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks, Issue is resolved, I set modulepath and compile time issues are gone